# How to stop request of data retreival from Spotfire to a Database

Tags: database, oracle, spotfire

There are data access tools where once we enter parameters and make selection to load data it starts by giving a pop up and while we wait for data to load there is an option to cancel it midway and we can update with new info and go on. When we use prompts its more direct and we can get data after the final selection/input.

But when using data on demand we can disable the Refresh Automatically and set option to get data every time we change the inputs. Is there a way to cancel data fetching in Spotfire.

What is the process when the data request goes from Spotfire to the database, how does it flow and if Spotfire Webplayer login window is closed midway during the request does the database request is cancelled or it runs and waits for thee Spotfire request/id.

Comment: I don't think it will stop the ODBC connected query. You'd have to kill that PID on the server side. I'm 99% sure of this if you are going through the web player.

Comment: is there a technical document available for the process that happens in the backend.

Comment: Well the spotfire server installation guide explains it pretty well but nothing overly specific. You Can use wireshark